# CheckBoxList check depend dropdownlist asp.net VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework

im trying to get value(true or false) from database but i want to select from role(`DropDownList`) to display if had permission or not in section

> dropdownlist and checkboxlist using entitdatasource

### i try this ( DropdownList(ddlRole))

```
 Protected Sub ddlRole_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlRole.SelectedIndexChanged
    Using context As New AGIP_dbModel.AGIP_dbEntities()
        For Each oItem As ListItem In ckSection.Items()
            Dim objPerm As tbl_permission = New tbl_permission()
            oItem.Value = objPerm.pre_status
        Next

    End Using
End Sub
```

### This how submite button work(Store in database)

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Using context As New AGIP_dbModel.AGIP_dbEntities()

        Dim id As Integer = ddlRole.SelectedValue

        Try

            Dim obj = context.tbl_permission.Where(Function(u) u.role_id = id)
            For Each permission As tbl_permission In obj.ToList
                context.tbl_permission.DeleteObject(permission)
                context.SaveChanges()
            Next


        Catch ex As Exception


        End Try
        For Each oItem As ListItem In ckSection.Items()
            Dim objPerm As tbl_permission = New tbl_permission()
            objPerm.role_id = ddlRole.SelectedValue
            objPerm.pre_status = oItem.Selected
            objPerm.section_id = oItem.Value
            context.tbl_permission.AddObject(objPerm)
            context.SaveChanges()

        Next
        Response.Redirect("permission.aspx")
    End Using
End Sub
```

[image: permission.aspx]

### tbl_role

[image: tbl_role]

### tbl_section

[image: tbl_section]

### tbl_permission relationship with role and section

[image: tbl_permission]

[image]

Comment: Hi, do you have any code to show us?

Comment: check the update post please!

Comment: Can you show us sample data of how the roles and its permissions are stored in the database.

Comment: @CurseStacker see the update please

Comment: Not the code, the data stored in the database. The record of roles and its related permissions.

Comment: @CurseStacker sorry my mistake ,thats what u want ?

Comment: Yes it is. It will help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with usage of Entity yet so I hope you can get what I'm trying to do here.

Also not sure if checkbox has a Caption or Text property, kindly check.

```
Protected Sub ddlRole_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlRole.SelectedIndexChanged
    Using context As New AGIP_dbModel.AGIP_dbEntities()
        For Each oItem As ListItem In ckSection.Items()
            Dim objPerm As tbl_permission = New tbl_permission()
            If objPerm.section_name = oItem.Caption Then 'Check if the permission record is same with the caption of the current checkbox in iteration
                oItem.Checked = objPerm.pre_status
            End If
        Next oItem
    End Using
End Sub
```

You also need to modify your SQL query on returning the permission records to include the section_name if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

Finally   found The Answer:

```
Protected Sub ddlRole_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlRole.SelectedIndexChanged
        Using context As New BWJO_dbModel.BWJO_dbEntities


            Try
                For Each secTionItem As ListItem In ckSection.Items


                    secTionItem.Selected = False
                    For Each oItem As ListItem In ckSection.Items
                        Dim PermObj = context.tbl_permission.Any(Function(u) u.role_id = ddlRole.SelectedValue And u.permission_status = True And u.section_id = oItem.Value)
                        If PermObj = True Then
                            oItem.Selected = True
                        End If

                    Next


                Next
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try


        End Using


    End Sub
End Class
```